# Where are the templates?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

I have a question where the seemingly simple solution seems to be eluding me. I also don't see it anywhere online.  When I create a site template with Sharepoint Online where are they stored? I need to delete one but I can't seem to locate where they are kept. If I cannot go directly to a URL and just "delete it", is there a way to do this programmatically with powershell?

Comment: how you create the template? development or Saving the site as template?

Comment: You don't work for MS do you? I don't want you to shut down or block that work-around. :)

Comment: I am not Msft employee and I have no power to shut down things in sharepoint...lol...which workaround u talking about....mainly if msft come to know a things, they called it un  supported

Comment: Ok good. Lol. They don't like it when you don't work for them but you come up with a workaround to what they disabled. :) 

In Sharepoint designer go to > site options > highlight SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled property > click modify > change "false" to "true" > click "apply" > click "ok".

Comment: U are talking about publishing template when there is no option for save as template, right? They know it but it is unsupported

Comment: not publishing template specifically. Any custom template.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the site template using the `Site settings > save as template` options,

It will be in Solution Gallery which can be access by this:

- Click Settings  SharePoint Online Public Website Settings button and
  then click `Site Settings`.

  In the `Web Designer Galleries` section, click `Solutions`.

Here is good article about it: [Create and use site templates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371B0F-00E0-4C49-A844-34759EBDD989)

Comment: I didn't use site settings > save as template. I used Sharepoint designer > save site as template. Would it still be in solutions?